# raspberry pi 2 windows iot remote debugger does not appear to be running

Tags: visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to debug an example app on a raspberry pi 2 using windows 10 build 10074 with VS 2015RC.

I've successfully done this before but I'm currently getting this error re: The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running.

Seems like it would be simple to fix this but I can't find anything specific to VS2015 and IoT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The remote debugger should be started automatically when the RPi2 is booted. However, I too have seen this issue. If you do not wish to reboot your device then you should connect to your RPi2 via the [PowerShell interface](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/PowerShell.htm). Once you have connected enter ps. If you do not see one or more instances of msvsmon running then you can start the debugger by changing directory to c:\RDBG and running the command StartOneCoreRdbg.cmd. This will never return to a command prompt though.

Mark Radbourne [MSFT]

Comment: Running net start WinRM also did the trick. So does rebooting. Will try running RDBG should it happen again. Marking as answer since rebooting will start the remote debugger. At least most of the time.

Comment: Mark, I have a mismatch between VS and RemoteDebugger on the PI2. I have the new rTools_setup_ARM but how do I deploy it to the PI?

Answer (score 2):

Properties Project ->Debug->Autehntication Mode: Universal.

Try, it's work.

Answer (score 2):

Use iot dashboard and in "my devices" and click on "open in device portal". In there would a option "Debugging" click on start visual studio debugger. Then deploy the app

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was setting up RPi3 for my friend and none of the above options worked in my friend's case when she walked herself into this issue.

The option "click on start visual studio debugger" only works if the MSVSMON.exe has been previously deployed onto the RPi3. This can be done manually using powershell or VS does it automatically the first time you try to do remote debugging.

When you start remote debugging the first time in VS connected to the RPi3, it will deploy the MSVSMON.exe to the RPi3 and start it. From there onwards, the debugger may stop if you reboot the RPi3 but it will stay deployed onto the RPi3.

In my friend's case, VS would fail deploying the app every single time, no matter if the firewall was turned off or if netstart Winrm command was issued. Tried all the authentication methods but it didn't work.

Ultimately I asked her to uninstall VS completely and then install VS + Update 2 + latest Win 10 SDK out there.

**This reinstallation of the VS helped resolve the issue.** After reinstallation, VS was now able to deploy to the RPi3 using the 'Universal' Authentication method.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

Visual Studio -> Tools -> NuGet Packet Manager -> Packet Manager Settings -> Check both boxes under "Package Restore"